# Skip save if a condition fails in before_save

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, exception

I have created a table with polygons as one of its columns. I don't want to create a new row if the new polygon intersects with any of the polygons already present in the table. I am able to achieve this using `raise` within the `before_save` method. However, I don't want to raise an exception because I am reading the data from a csv file and I want to continue reading the file even if an entered data fails this check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
#app/models/some_model.rb
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :custom_validation

  def custom_validation
    #... your validation conditional here. should return true or false
  end
end

#do this
SomeModel.create(foo: "bar")

#do NOT use the bang create!
SomeModel.create!(foo: "bar")
```